# Convert from UTC time when saving to Sp-List to Local Time

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

```
var fromDate = new Date(result);
var fromLoc = fromDate.getTimezoneOffset();

var toDate = new Date(result2);
var toLoc = toDate.getTimezoneOffset();




var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>'
    + fromLoc + '</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toLoc +
    '</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>');
```

var fromDate gets 01:00 to 01:30 and result gets 00:00 and result to 00:30
fromLoc gets the value -60 and also toLocal.

The Sp.CamlQuery(); gets fromLoc -60 and toLoc also, but when saving the utc time dont get right. it doesnt remove one hour why?

Comment: Did you check the DST (daylight saving time) settings of both locations? DST ends at late October or early November.